# Copy a row from one sheet to a second one if it contains a certain value

Tags: vba, excel, copy, row

I am new to VBA and found what I thought was the answer to my question but is not working. If on my Sheet1 column F contains the value `"A - 6:30PM"` then I would like the entire row to be copied to a second sheet.

This was the code I was previously using. What is going wrong?

```
Sub Test()
  For Each Cell In Sheets(1).Range("F:F")
    If Cell.Value = "A - 6:30PM" Then
        matchRow = Cell.Row
        Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select
        Selection.Copy

        Sheets("A").Select
        ActiveSheet.Rows(matchRow).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("A").Select
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What is not working in this code?

Comment: it only copies the first row that has "A - 6:30PM" and that's it

Comment: And you want to copy all rows containing that value?

Comment: Yes! If the cell has "A - 6:30PM" then I would like the entire row to be copied to the second sheet

Answer (score 0):

This is a cleaner way to do it.
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

```
    Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet
    Dim lRow as Long

    'Starting at row 1 loop through each row of the used range.
    lRow = 1
    Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

        If ws.Range("F" & lRow).Value = "A - 6:30PM" then

            Rows(lRow & ":" & lRow).Select
            Selection.Copy

            Sheets("A").Select
            ActiveSheet.Rows(lRow).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Sheets("A").Select

        End If

        lRow = lRow + 1
        ws.Range("A" & lRow).Activate
    Loop
```

I'm not sure how your paste code knows what row to paste each row to.  But if you need to keep track of a row to paste to just add another counter for the second sheet.

```
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet
'Starting at row 1 loop through each row of the used range.
Dim lRow as Long
Dim lTargetRow as Long

lTargetRow = 1
lRow = 1
Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    If ws.Range("F" & lRow).Value = "A - 6:30PM" then
        Rows(lRow & ":" & lRow).Select
        Selection.Copy

        Sheets("A").Select
        ActiveSheet.Rows(lRow).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("A").Select

       lTargetRow = lTargetRow + 1
    End If

    lRow = lRow + 1
    ws.Range("A" & lRow).Activate
Loop
```

Comment: For some reason:  Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count line is not working and giving me the '424' error. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: hmm, i've used that hundreds of time. Let me research

Comment: Added the declaration of ws and set it.  See above Dim ws line and the Set ws line.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not work. Now it just runs through the spreadsheet and doesn't even copy anything to sheet 2.

Comment: where I put the comment "'Copu lrow here" Did you put your copy code?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm very new to VBA what exactly is a copy code?

Comment: ok, i put you code that was copying the row into the if statement. Please look at the code i put in and where i put it.  That may help you learn that you had the code that was copying, and i just put what you had into the loop that i provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `Sheets("A").Select` with `Sheets(1).Select` at the very end of your code.